# NoSuchMethodError on a method that does exist at runtime on my android device

Tags: java, android, qr-code, nosuchmethoderror

thanks for taking the time to read this. I am experiencing a very strange 'NoSuchMethodError' in a project I'm working on involving Android. I can't figure this out as it defies all of my logic.

```
package com.project.qrcode

import android.security.KeyStore;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.config.ZXingLibConfig;
import jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.integrator.IntentIntegrator;
import jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.integrator.IntentResult;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ZXingLibConfig zxingLibConfig;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private TextView txtScanResult;
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance();
    SecretKeyStore secretKeyStore = new SecretKeyStore();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );

    byte[] hashedBytes;
    String decoded;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                startActivity(new Intent("android.credentials.UNLOCK"));
              } else {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.android.credentials.UNLOCK"));
              }
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(getPackageName(), "No UNLOCK activity: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        zxingLibConfig = new ZXingLibConfig();
        zxingLibConfig.useFrontLight = true;
        txtScanResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_result);

        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);

        //Set a listener on the scan button
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!checkIfKeyStored()) {
                    Toast keyerror = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You need to complete setup first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    keyerror.show();
                    return;
                }
                IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MainActivity.this, zxingLibConfig);
            }
        });
        Log.v(getPackageName(), "Listener set on scan button");

        Button setupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setup_button);

        // Set a listener on the setup button
        setupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkIfKeyStored()) {
                    Log.v(getPackageName(), "Key is already stored");
                    Toast keyerror = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have already completed setup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    keyerror.show();
                    return;
                }
                Log.v(getPackageName(), "Key not stored, proceeding with setup");
                IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MainActivity.this, zxingLibConfig);
            }
        });
        Log.v(getPackageName(), "Listener set on setup button");
    }

    protected boolean checkIfKeyStored() {
        String[] keyNames = ks.saw("");

        if( keyNames.length == 0 ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // IF setup is done i.e. key is stored send to server
    // Otherwise store on phone

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.v(getPackageName(), "Scanned QRCode");

        if (requestCode == IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE) {
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (scanResult == null) {
                Log.v(getPackageName(), "Scanned nothing");
                return;
            }

            //Contents of the QRCode
            Log.v(getPackageName(), "Scan complete, getting result");
            final String result = scanResult.getContents();
            Log.v(getPackageName(), "Scanned the following code "+ result);

            //If there is already a secret key stored i.e. setup already done
            if (checkIfKeyStored()) {
                Log.v(getPackageName(), "Key already stored, encrypting");
                try {
                    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                    Log.v(getPackageName(), "Got SHA1PRNG instance");

                    byte[] keyBytes = ks.get("twofactorkey"); 
                    byte[] resultBytes = result.getBytes("UTF-8");

                    Log.v(getPackageName(), "Got Bytes");

                    outputStream.write( resultBytes );
                    outputStream.write( keyBytes );
                    Log.v(getPackageName(), "Wrote Bytes to output stream");

                    byte[] bytesToEncrypt = outputStream.toByteArray( );
                    Log.v(getPackageName(), "Wrote to Byte array");

                    hashedBytes = digest.digest(bytesToEncrypt);
                    decoded = new String(hashedBytes, "UTF-8");
                    Log.v(getPackageName(), "Coverted bytes to String");
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        txtScanResult.setText(decoded);
                        Log.v(getPackageName(), "Set TextView");
                    }
                });
            }
            else //This is the first time scanning a QRCode, i.e. Setup
            {
                Log.v(getPackageName(), "Key not stored, first time setup");

                byte[] resultBytes;

                try {
                    resultBytes = result.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    Log.v(getPackageName(), "Result byte array: " + resultBytes);

                    boolean success = ks.put("twofactorkey", resultBytes);

                    if (!success) {
                           int errorCode = ks.getLastError();
                           throw new RuntimeException("Keystore error: " + errorCode); 
                    }

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.v(getPackageName(), "Stored in keystore");

                Toast setupComplete = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have completed setup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                setupComplete.show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
package android.security;

public class KeyStore {
private boolean put(byte[] key, byte[] value) {
    execute('i', key, value);
    return mError == NO_ERROR;
}

public boolean put(String key, byte[] value) {
    Log.v("KEYSTORE", "Attempting put");
    return put(getBytes(key), value);
}
}
```

The error I am getting is..
02-24 15:25:55.689: E/AndroidRuntime(11016): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.security.KeyStore.put which occurs in the onActivityResult() method.

If you need the full logcat I can post that too.

You can see I have some Log messages planted throughout the code. The one inside put never prints out.

**EDIT 24/02/14:**
The above NoMethod exception has been solved by moving KeyStore.java into the same package as MainActivity.java - Thank you Lars

However I now have a new problem. Any time I try using ks.state() or ks.put() I get back a response back of AssertError: 5 - Which, according to KeyStore.java is a protocol error.

**Final Edit**
I figured out the above problem. Turns out the version of the KeyStore I am using from AOSP is for versions of Android below 4.2 only.

Comment: Possible that your call into the getBytes on your string cannot be encoded and "The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the given charset is unspecified."  Perhaps a check against an UnsupportedEncodingException could show something.

Comment: how do you know it does exists at run time?

Comment: Sorry that was bad phrasing on my part, I meant I get the error during runtime, even though the method does exist.

Answer (score 0):

**what is the reason for java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**

java doc says

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class
>   (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition
>   of that method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this
>   error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has
>   incompatibly changed.

in your code you call put method here

```
boolean success = ks.put("twofactorkey", resultBytes);
```

and you have a required method is in the `KeyStore` class

```
public boolean put(String key, byte[] value) {
    Log.v("KEYSTORE", "Attempting put");
    return put(getBytes(key), value);
}
```

but the problem is your compiled `KeyStore`(`KeyStore.class` file) has no required put method. I assume you have mistakenly altered the above put method and compiled both classes **alone** and ran `MainActivity` class. that's why you get that error

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback but I dont believe this is the problem. I am using Eclipse and upon saving each file is compiled. I then run the package as opposed to the single file.

I am using ZXIngLib and that is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

that kind of error appear when you are running some code on a older virtual machine.
in general thisd appen when your bitcode call a function that does not exist.

As far as i know `android.security;` does not exist, but `java.security;` does.

If that your custom class, i don't think you can put it into android's path, but i exoect a compiling error

Comment: `android.security` is defined by him

Comment: What do you think this is then http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/package-summary.html ?

Comment: Hi, android.security.Keystore is defined by me and taken from the AOSP.

Comment: where do you implement execute(...)?

btw i don't think you can put your own class into android.security package unless you modify your VM file.

Comment: I guess that since you have taken the Keystore class from the AOSP you have not altered the package name. If android itself loads the same class first during bootstrap, then your class will not be loaded. It will exist in compile time, but not in runtime, since the already loaded Keystore class will be the one used, and that class might not have the put() method.

Comment: Lars! That sounds exactly like the problem! How do I solve this? Put everything in the same package?

Comment: I put KeyStore.java in the same package but now everything else has stopped working. Any press of a button will cause a force close..

Comment: 02-24 17:37:39.942: E/AndroidRuntime(32354): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 17:37:39.942: E/AndroidRuntime(32354):  at com.project.twofactorfyp.MainActivity.checkIfKeyStored(MainActivity.java:92)
02-24 17:37:39.942: E/AndroidRuntime(32354):  at com.project.twofactorfyp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
02-24 17:37:39.942: E/AndroidRuntime(32354):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)

Comment: checkIfKeyStored was working before moving the file into the package

Comment: possibilities are ks is null, because of that you should look what it is doing. I you look at it you will find it really easy to fix